# enumerateChildNodes not finding child nodes in sprite kit - Swift 4

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a SpriteKit game where a ball moves across the screen. When the ball leaves the screen I would like to remove it from the parent and switch to a different scene (GameOverScene).

I am using `enumerateChildNodes` however it doesn't as if that is working. I am not really sure what the problem is however I think it may have something to do with the parent/child relationship...

```
func createBall(forTrack track: Int) {

    setupTracks()

    player?.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "small")
    player?.name = "BALL"
    player?.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    ballValue = 1
    randFloat = Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)

    if randFloat > 0.001 {
        ballSpeed = randFloat / 50
    }
    else {
        ballSpeed = randFloat / 50
    }

    let ballPosition = trackArray?[track].position

    player?.position = CGPoint(x: (ballPosition?.x)!, y: (ballPosition?.y)!)
    player?.position.y = (ballPosition?.y)!

    if ballDirection == "right" {
        player?.position.x = 0
        moveRight()
    }
    else {
        player?.position.x = (self.view?.frame.size.height)!
        moveLeft(speed: ballSpeed)
    }

    self.addChild(player!)

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node: SKNode, nil) in
        if node.position.x < -100 || node.position.x > (self.size.width) + 100 {
            print("balls Out")
            node.removeFromParent()
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            self.gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
            self.gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            self.view?.presentScene(self.gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }

}
```

I call this function twice, first in `override func didMove()`:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    createHUD()
    createBall(forTrack: track)

}
```

And second in `override func touchesBegan`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
        let node = self.nodes(at: location).first

        if node?.name == "BALL" {
            currentScore += ballValue
            player?.removeFromParent()
            createBall(forTrack: track)
        }
        else {
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

update:

The line `self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node: SKNode, nil) in` works so it is not a child parent relationship issue. The `if statement` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reading your code I think it's not about a solution, but a different approach. These suggestions will make your life easier:

1. Start with a smaller code, avoid or comment out all unneeded (like the if randFloat)
2. Force unwrap `player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "small")!` with the **!** because you actually want to crash if the initialization fails, then you can get rid of all ?
3. in touchesBegan, better use `for touch in touches {` as it is more simple to manage
4. `let location = touch.previousLocation(in: self)` you probably mean `let location = touch.location(in: self)`
5. *When the ball leaves the screen I would like to remove it from the parent* so this is something happening at some time in the game. You would like to call your `self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") {` into the update call, not every time you touch the screen

If this is not enough, feel free to post the least amount of code to make a playground and let me test it for you :]

Comment: The only thing I couldn't get to work was 2. I didn't show this but I initialize player var at the top `var player : SKSpriteNode?` and when I switch the '?' with '!' and remove all the other '!' it give s 'Fatal Error'. Other then that everything here worked perfectly and anyone reading this question with the same problem should look over this answer.

Comment: That's curious, I use it all the time with this purpose. Thanks for your comment :]